# Memory Access Exceedingly Slow For a Simple Loop Through an Array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, arrays, performance

I am taking about 50 times as long as expected to loop through a simple assignment. My first reaction was that I had disordered my memory access in the arrays, resulting in cache misses. This doesn't seem the case, however.

The pixel value assignment and updating the arrays takes a dogs age. Do any one of you folks have an inclining as to why this is happening? (I am compiling for an iPod with an A4)

```
memset(columnSumsCurrentFrameA, 0, sizeof(unsigned int) * (_validImageWidth/numSubdivisions) );
memset(rowSumsCurrentFrameA, 0, sizeof(unsigned int) * (_validImageHeight/numSubdivisions) );

int pixelValue = 0;
int startingRow = 0;
int startingColumn = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < _validImageHeight/numSubdivisions; i++)
{
    int index = (i + startingRow) * _imageWidth;
    for( int j = 0; j < (_validImageWidth/numSubdivisions); j++)
    {
        pixelValue = imageData[index + startingColumn + j];
        columnSumsCurrentFrameA[j] += pixelValue;           
        rowSumsCurrentFrameA[i] += pixelValue;              
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you know it is taking 50 times longer you expected?  There is no timing code in your listing here.  If you try to display a bitmap, that is much slower than pixel writing.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! As for my issue, I found what I believe to be the problem. Though my pixel values were made to look as if they existed in main system memory, I suspect the values were stored on a section of memory dedicated to the GPU.  So, I was effectively requesting data from the GPU; a high latency operation. I mitigated the effects by performing a single memcpy for all the data from the previous memory space into a section I malloc'd myself.  This doubled my performance.  As Apple is a closed book on such matters I can't be certain, but I'm fairly sure this was the issue.

Comment: hotpaw2, you are correct sir!  I should have posted the timing measures.  My statement of 50 times slower than expected was based upon my reusing  a bit of code from another developer who posed benchmarks. These benchmarks were not entirely accurate, in reality I was getting about a 3x slowdown. See above for my solution.  Thanks again, fellows!

Answer (score 0):

The result of `_validImageWidth/numSubdivisions` must be an integer, are you sure that is always the case?

Also, you should calculate `_validImageWidth/numSubdivisions` before entering the double loops, it's not safe to assume your compiler takes care of it.

```
int limit = _validImageHeight/numSubdivisions;

for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++)
{
        int index = (i + startingRow) * _imageWidth;
        for( int j = 0; j < limit; j++)
        {
            pixelValue = imageData[index + startingColumn + j];
            columnSumsCurrentFrameA[j] += pixelValue;           
            rowSumsCurrentFrameA[i] += pixelValue;              
        }
}
```